# Direction of a vector

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, vectors

There is a question that says:
Let $f(x,y)=x^2y+y^2$ Fine the direction vector v, such that f increases rapidly in the direction v at the point (1,1). Find the maximum rate of change of f at $(1,1)$

My answer:
$$fx = 2xy$$
$$fy = x^2+2y$$

$$\nabla f(x,y) <2xy,x^2+2y> $$
 $$\nabla f(1,1) <2,3> $$

Maximum rate will be equal to the magnitude of the gradient which will be
$ \sqrt{2^2+3^2} = \sqrt{13}$

Now, this part is confusing.. Why is the directional vector $\vec{v} = <2,3> $

Usually, when the direction of the vector is given to calculate the directional derivate, it always isn't the same with what I get from $\nabla f(x,y)$

---

Edit:
So If I am to calculate the unit vector, it would be 
$$ \vec{u} = \frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{|v|}|}  = \frac{{<2,3>}}{\sqrt{2^2+3^2}} = < \frac{{2}}{\sqrt{13}} , \frac{{3}}{\sqrt{13}} > $$

And the directional derivative would be  $$\nabla f(1,1) * \vec{u} = \frac{{2}}{\sqrt{13}} + 2, \frac{{3}}{\sqrt{13}} * 3$$

Comment: I don't get it. If $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, then $f_y(x,y)\neq x^2+2y$.

Comment: Your calculations of the partial derivatives are incorrect.  Not sure how those came about.  Intuitively, your function gives the square of the distance of $(x,y)$ from the origin.  If you are at the point $(x,y)$ and you what to most rapidly increase that distance, then you want to travel directly away from the origin.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry there was a type, I edited it!

Comment: the point $(1,1)$ it is at the level set $1$ because $f(1,1)=1$, so the the gradient $<2,3>$ gives the direction perpendicular at the curve $x^2y+y^2=1$ starting at  the point $(1,1)$ on it.

Comment: @janmarqz So if the points were (2,2) then what would it be?

Comment: @MrProPop: now $f(2,2)=12$ so $(2,2)$ is at the level curve $x^2y+y^2=12$ and ${\rm grad} f(2,2)=[8,8]$, so at $(2,2)$ move into direction $(8,8)$. In my previous comment I made some mistakes... but not now.

Comment: Do some experiments with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=contour+plot+x%5E2y%2By%5E2%3D12,%7Bx,-12,12%7D,%7By,-12,12%7D

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to think about it.

Draw the level curve $x^2y + y^2 = 2.$ Note that $(1,1)$ lies on the curve.

If you want to move away from level as quickly as possible you want to move perpendicular to the level curve. And $\nabla f = (2,3)$ is perpendicular to the level curve.

Alternatively, the directional derivative  $=\nabla f\cdot \frac {\bf{u}}{\|\bf {u}\|}$ and $a\cdot b = \|a\|\|b\|\cos \theta$

If we what to maximize $\|\nabla f\|\cos \theta$ we want to chose a $\bf{u}$ such that $\cos \theta = 1$

Comment: Thanks! Can you please check my new update?

Comment: $(2,3)\cdot \frac {(2,3)}{\sqrt {2^2 + 3^2}} = \frac {2^2 + 3^2}{\sqrt {2^2+3^2}} = \sqrt {13}$